# Did Hamilton have a proof that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is cannot be turned into an $\mathbb{R}$-division algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, soft-question, math-history

It is well-known that $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be made into a non-commutative $\mathbb{R}$-division algebra if $n\ne 4$.

My question is whether there is a (slick) proof of this for $n=3$; in particular, I wonder if Hamilton had a proof of this result for $n=3$ which made him look at $n=4$ for discovering quaternions.

Comment: If you allow the division algebra not to be associative we can also take $n=8$.

Comment: See [Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)) and [Hurwitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras))

Comment: @MattS Of course, you are right. I am aware of the existence of octonions, but I am considering only associative algebras here.

Comment: I think he didn't. He was just struggling with $\mathbb{R}^3$ when he managed to define (the right) multiplication for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @PepperSausage Thanks for the links. Indeed, by "well-known" in my post I meant "Frobenius theorem." It seems to me that Hurwitz's theorem is a special case of that of Frobenius for finite dimensional algebras.

Comment: I believe that Hamilton discovered the quaternions thinking about numbers with the format $a+bj$, where $a,b$ are complex numbers and $j^2=-1$. The crucial step is to define $bj=j\overline{b}$. Then we can define $ij=k$.